# Blackberry Phone rebooting on app install

Tags: blackberry, reboot

On installing an application on a BlackBerry, the phone has to be rebooted to complete installation. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 3):

You can check ["What Is - The reason a reset is required when upgrading an application"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-reason-a-reset-is-required-when-upgrading-an-application/ta-p/445039).

One important thing is to completely exit the app before upgrading.